# Efficient way to append a generated object within an existing list on a JSON file?

Tags: python, arrays, json, object

I have a json file as follows:

```
{
    "counts": [
        {
            "date": "date", 
            "day": {
                "failed": "0", 
                "success": "0", 
                "total": "0"
            }, 
            "night": {
                "failed": "0", 
                "success": "0", 
                "total": "0"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "date": "05/12/2017", 
            "day": {
                "failed": "0", 
                "success": "0"
            }, 
            "night": {
                "failed": "1", 
                "success": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This json file i access and edit with:

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter

today = '05/15/2017'
shift = 'night'

def count_save_json(today, shift, status):

    with open('count.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    if today in map(itemgetter('date'), data['counts']):
        index = map(itemgetter('date'), data['counts']).index(today) #if today in map(itemgetter('date'), data['counts']) else None
        data['counts'][index][shift][status] = int(data['counts'][index][shift][status]) + 1
        print data
    else:
        new_count = {
                    "date": today,
                    "day": {
                            "success": 0,
                            "failed": 0
                            },
                    "night": {
                            "success": 0,
                            "failed": 0
                            }    
                    }

        new_count[shift][status] = 1
        data['counts'].append(new_count.copy())
        print data

    with open('count.json', 'w+') as fd:
        json.dump(data, fd, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

count_save_json(today, shift, 'success')
```

Its is functional and it does what i intend it to do, which is if variable today's value exists then update the corresponding value if not the push new object too array and start updating that new object until today changes again,  but the issue is that i feel is not or may not be the most efficient way to do so, as everytime the today variable changes and i need to add a new object to the array in the json file, the variable data from reading the json initially for processing will become bigger and bigger.

Say when i have a month of data the data = json.load(f) variable will be huge (technically containing the entire contents of the json file at that moment) since then i have to open the json file again remove contents and place the new data completely instead of the portion i needed to add that is the new_count object.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Hope all that made sense.

---

As suggested by @martineau a version using shelve module:

```
import shelve

today = '05/15/2017'
shift = 'day'

def count_save_json(today, shift, status):

    s = shelve.open('count.db', writeback=True)
    try:
        if today in s:
            s[today][shift][status] += 1
        else:    
            s[today] = {
                            "day": {
                                "failed": 0, 
                                "success": 0
                            }, 
                            "night": {
                                "failed": 0, 
                                "success": 0
                            }
                        }
            s[today][shift][status] = 1
    finally:
        print s
        s.close()

count_save_json(today, shift, 'failed')
```

While dates change it will result in appending new data to the .db file with a comma separating the entries as follows:

```
{
    '05/19/2017': {
        'day': {
            'failed': 0, 
            'success': 1
        }, 
        'night': {
            'failed': 0, 
            'success': 0}
    }, 
     '05/17/2017': {
         'day': {
             'failed': 0, 
             'success': 2
         }, 
         'night': {
             'failed': 0, 
             'success': 0
         }
     }, 
     '05/16/2017': {
         'day': {
             'failed': 0, 
             'success': 2
         }, 
         'night': {
             'failed': 0, 
             'success': 0
         }
     }
}
```

So no matter what date the entire file is not being re-written as with the json version.

Comment: Since this is a working solution, I would suggest you head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get it reviewed. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware that was an option will proceed right ahead. Cheers

Comment: Could you store each date's data in a separate json file? This would make it possible to minimize the reading and writing of a whole month's data every update.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a database. Python comes with the `dbm` module. You could also use the `shelve` module which essentially provides a persistent, disk-based, dictionary-like object that can store most Python objects as values.

Comment: @martineau i definitely though about it but i also feel is gonna be a a bit of a task if i ever want to get data out of the records, but yeah ill work on a version that has creates json with today as file name and see how it goes. I was not aware of dbm and shelve ill start reading about it... Thanks a Lot

Comment: AlejandroSuarez: It's actually extremely  easy to use either the `dbm` or `shelve` modules because for the most part the objects/databases they create act like Python dictionaries and opening one for use doesn't require reading the entire thing into memory. Nor does making updates.

Comment: Indeed it was extremely easy using shelve, cannot believe how simple it was :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is not a code question per se, but it still touches data structures and approaches.

To my understanding, you're right that this approach will lead to a slower and slower performance over time, as you essentially looping over the records. It shouldn't be a large burden in the 5 upcoming years, though.

Yet, there is an easy (and widely used) solution to that - don't use lists, use hashtables, or in python terms, dictionaries!

Just store your records like:

```
{
    "counts": {
       "2017": {
         "12": {
           "05": {
     {
            "day": {
                "failed": "0", 
                "success": "0"
            }, 
            "night": {
                "failed": "1", 
                "success": "1"
            }
        }
}}}}}
```

This way you can cheaply check if your date is in there, with the same performance. With that to be said, if you're worried about having large dataset, you should definitely walk away from having single json file in the first place! Just use Mongo/SQL/SQLite/ZeroDb....

Comment: Great! I will try that approach im not expecting to collect that much data that's why i was looking a simple approach and it makes sense, i can even probably separate json files monthly of even yearly if it grows to big for my taste which by then ill probably already started looking at proper databases. Thanks a lot this answer gave me a different perspective, as stands it seems i needed it :). Cheers